# Downloading an Xbox 360 update fails every time

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

I'm updating the Xbox 360 software, but it stops midway and says "updated failed". I've done this a few times but I get the same error every time. What gives?

Comment: Does it provide any status code for the failure?

Comment: So, any of the answers a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes inserting some external storage helps.

1. Insert a USB flashdrive
2. Go to Settings > Storage Settings > 1st option (to use the flashdrive as a memory unit for the Xbox)

OR

1. Open the hidden hard disk cover near the cooling vent.
2. Insert your Hard disk

Now try updating again. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to clear your HDD cache. You need to enter a key combination at the storage device management screen. Microsoft has a guide for this.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971755

Comment: Now you just go to your HDD, press Y for device options, then select clear system cache. You may have to redownload some game updates too if so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... You can diwnload the update to a USB or CD/DVD.
http://www.xbox.com/en-AU/Support/UpdateSteps